# How to return a box to self?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I experience difficulties to develop my personal first project.

To get the essential my code looks like this:

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    type Out: MyTrait;

    fn foo(&self) -> Box<Self::Out>;
}

pub struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait>(Box<T>);

impl<T: MyTrait> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
    type Out = Self <>;

    fn foo(&self) -> Box<Self::Out> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}
```

The error message I get is :

> expected struct `MyStruct<T>` found reference `&MyStruct<T>`

I tried many things but I can't find how to return a box to self...

I have another question: actually MyTrait extends another trait and I have many struct that implement MyTrait so in my code I have many impl, one for each trait by struct and I find it really verbose, isn't it possible to implement all methods (from a trait and all its parents) at once (like in java) ? Or is there syntactic sugar to implement methods with closures ?

Thanks

Comment: In the `foo` method, `self` is a reference, therefore its concrete type is indeed `&MyStruct<T>`. If you want to return the correct type, you have to pass `self` by value, which will move it into the Box.
What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: First, the error tells you that you've tried to move out of a reference, which is disallowed by Rust's single-ownership principle. This usually means that you have an error in your logic (you either want to return a reference or you have to consume the instance - as a newcomer from another language, it can be hard to wrap your head around the entire ownership thing).
Second, yes, you can implement a trait for a generic type with some trait bounds: `impl<T: SomeTrait> MyTrait for T {...}` (it's called a "Blanket Implementation")

Comment: Thanks for your answers !
I want to do formal calculus so I have a 'Function' trait and another expending it 'Differentiable' containing a 'diff(&self) -> Box<Self::Out>' method (with type Out: Function) ; my structures are functions like 'Add<T: Function, U: Function>(Box<T>, Box<U>)', 'Const(f64)', 'Id()', 'Exp<T: Function>(Box<T>)', ...
I want a function to be immutable and represented like a tree, containing only references to other functions, except for the primitive ones like Id(), Const(f64) or Poly(Vec<f64>) but I don't want a function to own another.
-->see next comment

Comment: For some there's no problem but some, for example exponential references itself in its derivate ((e^u)'=u' e^u) then I set type Out = Mul<T::Out, Self<>> ('Mul' represents product) and I tried this implementation :
fn diff(&self) -> Box<Self::Out> {
    Box::new(Mul(self.0.diff(), Box::new(self)))
}, thus my problem...

Comment: If you are trying to use this to downcast a `Box<MyTrait>` to a `Box<MyStruct>`, I'm afraid I will have to tell you this won't work. A `MyTrait<Out = MyStruct>` is a different type then a `MyTrait<Out = MyOtherStruct>`. Associated types are part of the total type. This is so that the compiler actually knows what the child type is. As soon as the compiler looses track, which is probably what you are trying to achieve, your only option is RTTI and [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/).

Answer (score 4):

`Box` needs to **own** `self`. You cannot pass a reference into it, it has to be the actual `self` object.

This works:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {
    type Out: MyTrait;

    fn foo(self) -> Box<Self::Out>;
}

pub struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait>(Box<T>);

impl<T: MyTrait> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
    type Out = Self;

    fn foo(self) -> Box<Self::Out> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}
```

---

Further remarks:

I'm unsure why you need that function, but it seems to me like you are trying to downcast from a boxed dyn trait to an actual type.

Sadly, this won't work this way. It's impossible for the compiler to figure out which type was the original type if your `Box<dyn MyTrait>` doesn't contain that information any more. That's why you need the `Out` associated type here, but you probably didn't yet realize that this means you can no longer store a `Box<dyn MyTrait>` object. It's now a `Box<dyn MyTrait<Out = MyStruct>>` object, which cannot be mixed with other `MyTrait` types any more.

If you really want to achieve that, there are several options. RTTI is one option, with the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/) trait.

Another one would be a Visitor pattern, which could resolve this:

```rust
pub trait Visitor {
    fn visit_mystruct(&mut self, s: &mut MyStruct);
}

pub struct MyVisitor;
impl Visitor for MyVisitor {
    fn visit_mystruct(&mut self, s: &mut MyStruct) {
        println!("Visited MyStruct: {:?}", s.0);
    }
}

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn visit(&mut self, visitor: &mut dyn Visitor);
}

pub struct MyStruct(i32);

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn visit(&mut self, visitor: &mut dyn Visitor) {
        visitor.visit_mystruct(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut obj: Box<dyn MyTrait> = Box::new(MyStruct(42)) as Box<dyn MyTrait>;
    let mut visitor = MyVisitor;

    // Here is no information any more about the actual type of `obj`.

    // Visitor gets the type resolved again
    obj.visit(&mut visitor);
}
```

```
Visited MyStruct: 42
```

A visitor pattern is especially useful in cases like tree structures, because it can be recursively applied to children. It is commonly used in compilers.

Another alternative would be to use an `Enum` instead of a `Box<dyn Trait>`.

Although those are all just based on assumptions now.